# Easy way to sort default array in Vala

Tags: sorting, vala

I tried it like this, but it doesn't work. And I think it's too complicated a way to sort an array. I need something like System.Array.Sort () of C#

```
int[] data = { 3, 9, 2, 7, 5 };
var arr = new Array<int> ();
arr.append_vals (data,data.length);

arr.sort((a, b) => {
    return (int) (a > b) - (int) (a < b);
});

for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
    print(@"$(arr.index(i))\t");
}
```

also tried that, the array is still not sorted.

```
using Posix;
int cmpfunc(ref int a, ref int b) {
    return (int) (a > b) - (int) (a < b);
}
void main() {
    int[] data = { 3, 9, 2, 7, 5 };

    Posix.qsort (data, data.length, sizeof(string), (Posix.compar_fn_t) cmpfunc);
    foreach (int st in data) {
        print(@"$st\t");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Posix.qsort` function needs to know the size of each element in the array, `sizeof(int)`, but you're giving it the size of a different type, `sizeof(string)`.

Comment: okay thanks, it's working now. But still, is there really no easier way to sort an array without a function comparison Declaration? (and not lambda too)

Comment: The array is a pretty low level type in Vala and it only represents a C pointer and a length. For "easy" sorting and other functionality you want a higher level data type like a `Gee.ArrayList` (which implements `Gee.List.sort`).